# Progress Bar Value > Integer doesn't work in if statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, audio, progress-bar

I have an application I am testing out where audio is played and an action is performed when the audio is played. I have the audio captured in a progress bar which works flawlessly however after I start the program everything will work but the if statement below. Is there something I am missing? I am using NAudio to capture the audio etc as well.

All audio is going to the progress bar when selecting any audio source and will detect at the right level. When I click on a button in the Windows Form Application it right clicks fine, but when I have audio coming through past a certain level it doesn't right click again which is what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is the main code which gets the audio and the mouse buttons:

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

        public void DoMouseClick()
        {
            uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
            uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
        }

        private WaveIn recorder;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            recorder = new WaveIn();
            recorder.StartRecording();
            MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            var devices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active);
            audioSourcesList.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray());
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (audioSourcesList.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var device = (MMDevice)audioSourcesList.SelectedItem;
                device.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = false;
                Label.Text = (Math.Round(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100)).ToString();
                progressBar.Value = (int)(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100);
            }
        }
```

Here is the block that starts the main program and where it seems to not work:

```
        private void test()
        {
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                DoMouseClick();

            if (progressBar.Value >= 5)
                {
                    DoMouseClick();
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    DoMouseClick();
                }
        }
```

Comment: `if` statements work fine... so does the step debugger... have you tried to debug this? When you did, and inspected the variables, did you notice anything differing from your expectations ?

Comment: I have tried debugging but cannot find anything wrong. It just isn't executing the if statement? Or the progress bar value isn't being converted to a number which it should? I think I would be able to use it off of the label that gives the actual number but I wouldn't know where to start converting the string into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

*I did not work with NAudio but set up the threads you need.*

If the program stops when it reaches the if condition, it is because the control is for another thread and you are using it for another thread. With the BeginInvoke command, that allowed two threads to run asynchronously so that both threads had access to the required controls.

**If you want more information, refer to this link [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/calling-synchronous-methods-asynchronously)**

***change Form1 constructor to this***

```
public Form1()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate ()
    {
       recorder = new WaveIn();
       recorder.StartRecording();
    });
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
    t.Interval = 500;
    t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;

    t.Start();
    MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
    var devices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active);
    audioSourcesList.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray());
}
```

***Delete the timer1_Tick method and add the following lines to the program***

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate();

private void T_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(InvokeMethod));
}
void InvokeMethod()
{
    if (audioSourcesList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
       var device = (MMDevice)audioSourcesList.SelectedItem;
       device.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = false;
       Label.Text = (Math.Round(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100)).ToString();
       progressBar.Value = (int)(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100);
    }
}
```